# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'keys' when trying to use writerow

Tags: python

Trying to write a python **scraper** that **scrapes** data from webpage to csv file

Tried changing up the way I write the python file also if I remove the lines  dataFrameCleaned = cleanDataUp(dataFrame)
csvData(dataFrameCleaned)
the code runs however it doesnt write the data to the csv file

```
'''
write data to csv
'''
def csvData(dataFrame):
    with open('threads.csv', 'w+', newline='', encoding='utf8') as csvfile:
        fieldnames = ['post id', 'name', 'date of the post', 'post body']
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
        writer.writeheader()
        for posts in dataFrame:
            writer.writerow(posts)
        print('file write complete')


'''
defaults
'''
if __name__ == "__main__":
    path = str(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)))+'/data/'
    reload(sys)
    fieldnames = ['post id', 'name', 'date of the post', 'post body']
    dataFrame = pd.DataFrame(columns=fieldnames)
    url = 'http://www.oldclassiccar.co.uk/forum/phpbb/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?t=12591'
    urlList = [url]

    soup = get_soup(url)

    while True:
        newUrlSuffix = getURL(soup)
        if newUrlSuffix == '':
            break
        newUrl = 'http://www.oldclassiccar.co.uk/forum/phpbb/phpBB2/' + newUrlSuffix
        print("Adding new URL to list..")
        urlList.append(newUrl)
        soup = get_soup(newUrl)
    
    for link in urlList:
        print("Getting data from URL:" + link+ '\n\n\n')
        dataFrameNew = extractData(link)
        dataFrame = pd.concat([dataFrame,dataFrameNew])
    dataFrameCleaned = cleanDataUp(dataFrame)
    csvData(dataFrameCleaned)

The function for cleanDataUp
def cleanDataUp(dataFrame):
    dataFrame = dataFrame.reset_index(drop=True).dropna()
    return dataFrame
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scraper.py", line 127, in <module>
    csvData(dataFrameCleaned)
  File "scraper.py", line 96, in csvData
    writer.writerows(posts)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/csv.py", line 158, in writerows
    return self.writer.writerows(map(self._dict_to_list, rowdicts))
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/csv.py", line 148, in _dict_to_list
    wrong_fields = rowdict.keys() - self.fieldnames
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'keys'
```

Answer (score 4):

In `writer.writerow(posts)`, where `writer` is of type [csv.DictWriter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter) , the argument is supposed to be a dictionary e.g.

```
writer.writerow({'first_name': 'Baked', 'last_name': 'Beans'})
```

But as the error says, `posts` is a string instead of a dictionary, hence the error `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'keys'`

Perhaps your `cleanDataUp(dataFrame)` is returning you a list of strings, but you want a list of dictionaries, you need to check that function to ensure it returns the correct output to pass to `csvData()` function

Comment: my cleanDataUp function is defined as:

def cleanDataUp(dataFrame):
    dataFrame = dataFrame.reset_index(drop=True).dropna()
    return dataFrame

Comment: Hi @MEANStack Please add it to the question, and unfortunately, I am not an expert on pandas, so I cannot help you with this function! But you want to ensure `dataFrame` is a list of dictionaries

Comment: Great! Glad to help! :) Please consider marking the answer as accepted by clicking the tick next to the answer @MEANStack I also suggest you to read up on: stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers Have a good day :)